What was the last major-brand x/86 PC to have a 14.318 MHz NTSC clock on the bus?
Boca Raton put it on the ISA bus so it would be easy to build a TV monitor.
The 16-bit bus was an extension of ISA, so I assume it was there.
I think most 386s still had an ISA bus. 486s too, I believe. I don't remember, even though I sold them.
Bonus curiosity: Did MicroChannel or EISA retain the NTSC clock?

@StephenKitt No, I'm referring to ISA bus pin B30, which was marked OSC. It was the 14.31818 MHz used for CGA sync. The same crystal fed the bus again as the famous 4.77 MHz clock on pin  B20.  It was marked CLK. I just wondered how long this went on before decent people put a stop to it.

Ah, I see! My mistake. That signal was even decorrelated from the main CPU clock on IBM PCs running faster than 4.77MHz, starting with the AT, so as you say it could have lasted as long as the ISA bus (which is still available on industrial motherboards!).

Any machine with a fast enough clock could generate a 14.3818Mhz signal using a frational clock divider.  Generating the signal from a symmatric 33Mhz clock would yield 15ns jitter (out of a 70ns period) which might be unacceptably high, but at higher clock speeds that would be less of a problem.

@supercat It's usually the other way around - 486/Pentium era machines used a 14.318 MHz crystal with a PLL chip to generate all other necessary timer/system/bus/memory/keyboard/etc controller clocks. Except for RTC and Ethernet related clocks. You needed the 14.318 MHz divided by 12 as the base for 8254 PIT anyway.

I doubt it will be possible to pinpoint a specific major-brand PC as the last to ship with a correct 14.31818MHz signal on the B30 ISA pin. Pentium III-based systems have been documented as supporting it; PIIX4 was the last Intel chipset with native ISA, and ISA support is known to have degraded with later systems (ask anyone trying to use ISA audio cards), so that might be the end of the road. However the clock made available on B30 isn’t tied to the chipset, so changing chipsets wouldn’t necessarily affect it, and specific systems would have to be checked to try to answer your question.
EISA carries all the ISA signals on the ISA part of the connector, including the clock signal on B30. MCA isn’t backwards-compatible with ISA, but it also includes a 14.3MHz signal on pin B04.
